# Perl - creating text files with some data in lesser time - using threading

Tags: multithreading, perl

Whats the best way to generate 1000K text files? (with Perl and Windows 7) I want to generate those text files in as possible in less time (possibly withing 5 minutes)? Right now I am using Perl threading with 50 threads. Still it is taking longer time.

What will be best solution? Do I need to increase thread count? Is there any other way to write 1000K files in under five minutes? Here is my code

```
    $start = 0;
    $end = 10000;
    my $start_run = time();
    my @thr = "";

    for($t=0; $t < 50; $t++) {
        $thr[$t] = threads->create(\&files_write, $start, $end);
        #start again from 10000 to 20000 loop
        .........
    }

    for($t=0; $t < 50; $t++) {
        $thr[$t]->join();
    }

    my $end_run = time();
    my $run_time = $end_run - $start_run;
    print "Job took $run_time seconds\n";
```

I don't want return result of those threads. I used detach() also but it didn't worked me. 
For generating 500k files (with only size of 20kb) it took 1564 seconds (26min). Can I able to achieve within 5min?

Edited: The files_write will only take values from array predefined structure and write into file. thats it.

Any other solution?

Comment: This depends on so many factors – but mainly on what `files_write` is actually doing. Could you [edit] your question to include more information? Also, how long does the code currently take, and how long does it take when you *remove* the threading?

Comment: Spreading the files across multiple directories would probably help...

Comment: Actually I wanted to save all files under same folder.

Comment: Again: try a version without any threading – replace the two loops by `files_write($start, $end)` etc.. I suspect that should run in roughly half the time. Threads induce various overheads which we hereby remove, and switching from parallel to sequential writes should remove unnecessary seeking (assuming you are using a HDD, not a SSD).

Comment: Amon, I initially tried without threads and it was taking way much more time. Then I moved to threading which atleast reduced some time but not as per my requirement.

Comment: When you say 1000K files do you mean one million files? Or are you also referring to the size of the files? Do these files all have different content?

Comment: Yes one million files. random contents of same size 12 kb

Answer (score 1):

The time needed depends on lots of factors, but heavy threading is probably not the solution:

- creating files in the same directory at the same time needs probably locking in the OS, so it's better done not too much in parallel
- the layout how the data gets written on disk depend on the amount of data and on how many writes you do in parallel. A bad layout can impact the performance a lot, especially on HDD. But even a SDD cannot do lots of parallel writes. This all depends a lot on the disk you use, e.g. it is a desktop system which is optimized for sequential writes or is it a server system which can do more parallel writes as required by databases.
- ... lots of other factors, often depending on the system

I would suggest that you use a thread pool with a fixed size of threads to benchmark, what the optimal number of threads is for your specific hardware. E.g. start with a single thread and slowly increase the number. My guess is, that the optimal number might be between factor 0.5 and 4 of the number of processor cores you have, but like I said, it heavily depends on your real hardware.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Actually the hardware is desktop with 16GB of RAM and 1TB of HDD. So its not the issue. With threading I cam down to half and hour for 500K files which was more than hour earlier for sequential write. So was looking for a way to achieve this

Comment: I don't know how much you write, but Deskop HDD don't handle lots of parallel writes, server HDD do better. Like I said, try with different thread pool sizes what the optimal number of threads for your hardware is.

Answer (score 0):

The slow performance is probably due to Windows having to lock the filesystem down while creating files.

If it is only for testing - and not critical data - a RAMdisk may be ideal. Try Googling DataRam RAMdisk.

Comment: Yes Mark. Hardware is powerful. So I am thinking of any way in Perl to create such files less than 5m or taking lesser time... I tried playing with threads but still facing lot of time.